# Remove plain text before list a element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have HTML like. How can I remove plain text before list a.

```
<div class="listlink">This is plain text
    <a href="/search/label/blogger">blogger</a>
    <a href="/search/label/fashion news">Wordpress</a>
    <a href="/search/label/featured">Lifestyle</a>
    <a href="/search/label/slbfeatured">Google</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Or in plain javascript, and modern browsers `document.querySelector('.listlink').firstChild.remove()`

Comment: Thank you so much for another suggestion :).

Answer (score 5):

You can use **[`contents()`](https://api.jquery.com/contents/)** to get all child nodes including textnode. Then get first node using **[`eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)** and remove using **[`remove()`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/)**

```js
$('.listlink').contents().eq(0).remove()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="listlink">This is plain text
  <a href="/search/label/blogger">blogger</a>
  <a href="/search/label/fashion news">fashion news</a>
  <a href="/search/label/featured">featured</a>
  <a href="/search/label/slbfeatured">slbfeatured</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It is so useful to me. :)

Comment: @MinhAnh : glad to help :)